# Grouping calendar events by a date in Ember Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

A simple example here might be a list of events, such as a calendar, or just plain old listing that looks something like this

```
Monday

- event1
- event2

Tuesday

- event3
```

I'm not sure how to implement this in the app. There are two options as I see it:

### 1. server side

On the server pretend that there's actually some `Day` model which encapsulates the events. Which means you'd do something like this

```
def index
  events = Event.recent.group_by { |e| e.starts_at.to_date }.to_a

  days = data.map.with_index do |pair, index|
    # ember data seems to break without the ID here
    { id: index, date: pair[0], events: pair[1] }
  end

  render json: { days: days }
end
```

and then pretend on the client that you actually have a `Day` model which `hasMany` `Events`.

The template would then look something like

```
{{#each day in controller}}
  <h2>{{day.date}}</h2>

  {{#each event in day.events}}
    <p>{{event.name}}</p>
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

### 2. client side

I'm not sure how to implement this correctly, but it would basically mean that you would just return a list of events, and group them on the client. The server would then look just like

```
def index
  render json: Event.recent
end
```

but then the client won't be a simple matter of iterating in the template, as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I started playing with Ember today and only had an hour or two, so take this with a pinch of salt.

I have the same problem and found a [`group-by` computed property](https://github.com/embersherpa/examples/blob/master/app/utils/group-by.js) ([example](http://embersherpa.github.io/examples/#group-by)). Reading up on computed properties now. ;)